# Using QField for QGIS?

Tags: qfield

I am using Huawei MediaPad M3 Lite (Android 7.0). QField suits my requirement.
However at time I am unable to close the panel on the right after I have viewed the attributes of the layers.

The other problem is that I cannot snap pictures and position it on the map.

How can I rectify this problem because I need these to function well?

Comment: Do you try alternatives? For example [NextGIS Mobile](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-mobile/).

Answer (score 2):

The right panel (the features list/edit) can be closed using the "android back arrow" ( I don't know how is called)